# MYSQL: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1241

Im trying to get a list of products order by the amount sold and by date... I also want to display the products that havent been sold in the list so I tried doing a subquery but MYSQL is giving me this message:

Operand should contain 1 column(s)

This is the query im using:

```
SELECT product.product_id, product.product_brand_id, product.product_model_id, product.product_subcategory_id, product.product_retail_price, product.product_wholesale_price
FROM product
WHERE product.product_subcategory_id = $subcategory_id 
AND (SELECT SUM(product_sold.product_quantity) AS product_quantity_sold, SUM(product_sold.product_total_price) AS total_price_sold 
 FROM product
 INNER JOIN product_sold 
  ON product.product_id = product_sold.product_id
 INNER JOIN sales 
  ON sales.sales_id = product_sold.product_sales_id WHERE sales.sales_approved = '1' AND sales.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp' AND sales.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp')
```

Comment: Although my answer answers the question in your title, I think that in order for you to solve your actual problem (that of displaying all products, even the ones with no sales) you'll need to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` against the products table to view all products, even the ones with no linked field to other tables.

Comment: please check this as I did what you suggested, but its not working still http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387760/trouble-with-left-outer-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AND` operator expects a single value on either side, but you have this:

```
WHERE product.product_subcategory_id = $subcategory_id 
AND ( ... select that returns two columns)
```

The first operand is of the form `X = Y`, so that's a Boolean that evaluates as `true` or `false` (or `NULL` if the field is `NULL`), but the second operand isn't a Boolean.

To get this to work, you'll need to make the second operand of `AND` into a single-valued expression.